# Dynamic SQL Server Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

```
Declare @table varchar(50)
Declare @SQl_STR nvarchar(max)
set @table='test'
 Exec ('UPDATE '+@table+' SET 
RATE = REPLACE (RATE, ''.'', '','') ')
```

i am getting the following error --

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

I do not understand the error, please help

Comment: What datatype is RATE?

Comment: Data type of rate is varchar(255)

Comment: Works here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ab0b/1

Comment: Works for me too [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66781/1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66781/1)

Comment: Thank you guys for the support. Data type of rate was the problem. RATE was float, which i changed to varchar works fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the column RATE is of FLOAT datatype which should be converted to varchar before using your code

```
Declare @table varchar(50)
Declare @SQl_STR nvarchar(max)
set @table='test'
 Exec ('UPDATE '+@table+' SET 
RATE = REPLACE (ltrim(str(RATE,10,2)), ''.'', '','') ')
```

But the best way is to do this formation in the front end application

Comment: OP says the RATE column **is** varchar(255)

Comment: In that case there wont be problem. I guess it is float as the error says